# Is there a DAC (Digital to Analog Converter) in the iPhone Lightning Dock?

Tags: audio, headphones, lightning, iphone

I'm wondering if there's a DAC in the dock because the first sound loudness level is noticeable higher than the first level from iPhone 6+ when the iPhone is mount on the dock.

I suppose if there's a DAC that it has a lower resolution, i.e. less steps between silent and max loudness making each step wider on the dock.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, because the Lightning port is digital-only. The Apple Lightning to 30-Pin Adapter also contains a DAC, [according to MacRumors](http://www.macrumors.com/2012/10/11/apples-lightning-to-30-pin-adapter-torn-apart-reveals-several-chips-and-copious-glue/).

I don't know about the quality, but there is much more space for a good DAC in the dock then there is in the phone, so I wouldn't say it has to be worse.